# Is there any way to create two type of users using firebase authentication?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase along with my flutter project. The project has two types of users, one is a bookseller and the other one is a book buyer. Is there any way to implement separate signup for each type of user? In other words how my app is going to distinguish whether which type of user just signed in? If the book buyer logged in show him the book buyer dashboard else show the bookseller dashboard.
Or do you guys recommend making a separate firebase project for that?

Comment: during the signup period, take an extra param like 0 or 1.make an auth page in your app, which will check the param of the user just logged in, if the param is 1, redirect him to book seller dash board , else to the buyer dashboard

Comment: @xahid_rocks where to store the credentials of users? Would you suggest making a node for book buyers and booksellers in a real-time database that would store their emails and during login check against their emails and log in the user to the respective dashboard? Because I can't able to find anything which would help me mark the user type as book seller or book buyer inside firebase authentication.